# Pegar valor de entrada de um textbox em asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Como pegar o novo valor de entrada de um `textbox` ao clicar no botão ? Preciso fazer como se fosse um `update` que iria pro banco.

Comment: Essencialmente você vai enviar o valor para o servidor, talvez via AJAX, e lá o *controller* estará preparado para para liar com isto. Precisa dar mais informações do que está fazendo e do resultado desejado.

Comment: @bigown É uma coisa simples, só preciso pegar o valor de um textbox. Tipo em webforms: string teste = txtAlgo.Text;
Pode me dar um exemplo disso em mvc ?

Comment: Vou te dar um conselho como profissional: se você continuar olhando o MVC como o Web Forms, você sempre vai ter dificuldade e sempre vai usar as coisas da maneira errada. Vou responder assim mesmo, mas estou quase desistindo de te ajudar.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Pô desculpa ai mano, eu não manjo de mvc, eu manjo um pouco de web forms, por isso tenho essas dúvidas e pergunto aqui. Mas de boa.

Answer (score 2):

A maneira correta de fazer isso é através de um `<form>`. Usando MVC e Razor, se usa da seguinte forma:

```
@model MeuProjeto.Models.MeuModel

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MeuCampo)

    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
}
```

Obviamente, isto só faz sentido se você tiver um *Model* definido assim:

```
namespace MeuProjeto.Models
{
    public class MeuModel
    {
        public String MeuCampo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

O *Controller* irá receber os dados do formulário da seguinte forma:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MinhaAction(MeuModel model) 
{
    // O valor do campo em tela vai estar preenchido em 
    // model.MeuCampo
}
```

Comment: UPVOTE - Mais simples impossível. Disponsa novas respostas.